# Paramiko doesn't return grep correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, unix, paramiko

I am building myself a tool to run/kill scripts on my VPS over SSH. So far I was able to do exactly that (start or kill processes) but I can't manage to get the `ps -fA | grep python` command to work.

Some of my scripts actually spawn new scripts with `Popen` so I really need a way to check the PID of python scripts through SSH (and the name of the file the PID belongs to).

```
    ssh_obj = self.get_ssh_connection()
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_obj.exec_command('ps -fA | grep python')
    try:
        stdin_read = "stdin: {0}".format(stdin.readline())
    except Exception as e:
        stdin_read = "stdin: ERROR " + str(e)
    try:
        stdout_read = "stdout: {0}".format(stdout.readline())
    except Exception as e:
        stdout_read = "stdout: ERROR " + str(e)
    try:
        stderr_read = "stderr: {0}".format(stderr.readline())
    except Exception as e:
        stderr_read = "stderr: ERROR " + str(e)
    print("\n".join([stdin_read, stdout_read, stderr_read]))
```

But it doesn't works, the result it shows to me is:

```
stdin: ERROR File not open for reading
stdout: root       739   738  0 17:12 ?        00:00:00 bash -c ps -fA | grep python
stderr:
```

While the desired output would be something like:

```
PID: 123 - home/whatever/myfile.py
PID: 125 - home/whatever/myfile2.py
PID: 126 - home/whatever/myfile.py
```

That way I'll know which PIDs to kill for myfile script (123 and 126).

**Bonus question:** I'm not very linux experienced, does executing grep commands outside of the Terminal creates any PID that I have to manually kill?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to escape the pipe character by passing the whole statement in single quotes to a shell on the other end:

```
ssh_obj.exec_command("sh -c 'ps -fA | grep python'")
```

Alternatively you could try running `pgrep`:

```
ssh_obj.exec_command('pgrep python')
```

`pgrep` will search the current running processes that match the search string `python` and will send just the process IDs to the stdout.

Comment: `pgrep` wouldn't work for this. As I explained, there might be several different python scripts running and I need to know which ones to kill, so I need something more than just the pid (I need to know to which file each python script process belongs to).  Your first suggestion works great but only returns the first result, any fix for that?

Comment: Sorry, missed that you needed to know the file. Perhaps you could pass the `-a` switch to `pgrep` to list the full command line in addition to the pid. As for the grep itself only returning the first value, that's likely because you're calling `stdout.readline()` which would read up to the end of the first line. You'd need to call it repeatedly to get the other lines, or better, call `read()` which would read the whole lot.